# Need help to go back to Login page when clicked on Logout button

Tags: meteor

I need help to come to the sign in page once clicking on logout button from any of the inside pages in Meteor.My code is below which does not work,

**test.html**

```
<div class="container">
  Welcome <span>Deal Manager</span> | <a id="logout" href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
```

**test.js**

```
'click #logout': function() {       
        history.go("/login");       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I could try and find out the solution as below

replaced this

```
history.go("/login");
```

with

```
history.go(-2);
```

As per the pages I have replaced the path with the number.Hope this is a solution for the long run as well.